# Overriding 'nth-child' CSS property from the markup

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that possibly has an easy solution for those more proficient than me in HTML/CSS.

I've created a Gantt chart using plain old HTML/CSS, and alternate rows are coloured using the below CSS.

```html
.gantt-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.gantt-row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

.gantt-row:nth-child(even) .gantt-row-name {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
```

I'd like the ability to override the default colour of these alternate rows from back in the markup, however I can't simply add style="background-color: #87ceeb" to any of the DIVs below as this would likely not target the correct 'nth-child' CSS block.

```html
<div class="gantt-row">
  <div class="gantt-row-name">North Quay 1</div>
  <ul style="grid-template-columns: repeat(28, 1fr)" class="gantt-bars">
    <li style="grid-column: 8/16; background-color: #034B03;" class="tooltip">
      <a href="#">World Navigator</a>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this without resorting to jScript?

Thanks in advance,

Chris.